# How to make an indeterminate progress bar in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

How do you make an indeterminate progress bar in a WinForms application? In Silverlight and WPF, you would simply set the ProgressBar's `IsIndeterminate` property to true. However, this property does not exist in WinForms. How would you create an indeterminate progress bar in WinForms?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Set the `Style` on the `ProgressBar` to `Marquee`

Comment: HA would never have found it

Comment: This didn't work for me until I enabled visual styles (normally enabled by default): `System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();` at init

Comment: @EldritchConundrum Could you tell me how to do that , in detail , i mean im new to Winforms ,where should i add this line ?

Comment: @VasantRaval This line is usually found in your program's Main() function. That's where it is generated in the default template, when creating a new WinForms project.