# (Visual C#) How do you make one of those percentageless progress bars that scroll from the left to the right?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I'm not sure how to explain it, but I want the progress bar to act like the one on the Windows XP bootup screen. Is this possible? If so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which display tech you are using, but the general concept is an "indeterminate" progress bar. Styling it to look *exactly* like Windows XP could be a bit of a challenge, but to get the basics start with a `ProgressBar` and:

**In WinForms:**

Set `Style` to `Marquee` ([How to make an indeterminate progress bar in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129364/how-to-make-an-indeterminate-progress-bar-in-winforms))

**In WPF, WinRT, or UWP:**

Set `IsIndeterminate` to "True` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.isindeterminate(v=vs.110).aspx))